# Subgroups of generalized dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

A generalized dihedral group, $D(H) := H \rtimes C_2$,  is the semi-direct product of an abelian group $H$ with a cyclic group of order $2$, where $C_2$ acts on $H$ by inverting elements.

I know that the total number of subgroups of $D(H)$ is the number of subgroups of $H$ plus the sum of subgroup indices of $H$ ($\sum_{L \leq H}[H : L]$).

But I'm not interested in the actual subgroups, I only need the structures of subgroups of $D(H)$ up to isomorphism. Naturally all the subgroups of $H$ are (normal) subgroups of $D(H)$ and for each $L \leq H$ also $D(L) \leq D(H)$. But is that all or can there be other structures as well?

I read about the subgroups of semi-direct products in general, but the situation seemed quite complicated. Would it be easier to find just the structures?

Comment: For each subgroup $L$ of $H$, you have the subgroup $L$  itself, together with $|H:L|$ subgroups isomorphic to $D(L)$. The elements of $D(H) \setminus H$ are all involutions that act by inversion on $H$, so they are all essentially equivalent. Each subgroup isomorphic to $D(L)$ contains exactly $|L|$ of these involutions, which explains why there are $|H:L|$ such subgroups.

Comment: Ok, thanks for both. A follow-up if that's ok in comments: In addition to the subgroups of $H$ there can be other normal subgroups as well. When $2 \mid |H|$, then we can "separate" the non-trivial center out into a direct factor. For example, in $[24,14]$ we have $G = D(C_2 \times C_6) \cong Z(G) \times S_3$. This direct product gives us some other normal subgroups. Are these two classes all there are?

Comment: The normal subgroups $D(L)$  are those with $H^2 \le L$, where  $H^2 = \{h^2 : h \in H \}$. Your remark about the center spltting as a direct factor is not true in general. It is not true in $D(C_4)$ for example.

Comment: Thanks. My bad, just checked some small examples with GAP and made a hasty guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be a subgroup of $D(H)$.

If $K$ is not contained in $H$, then $K$ contains some $g \not\in H$. Then $g$ is an involution and $D(H) = H \rtimes \langle g \rangle$. Hence $K = (H \cap K) \rtimes \langle g \rangle$ and $K \cong D(H \cap K)$.